# Can mobs be equipped with armour based on drops from a loot table?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

I am making a RPG/Dungeon Crawler datapack and I want to procedurally make dungeons throughout the world. I have somewhat figured out how to make the dungeons, but I want the monsters to be random (e.g. what gear they have equipped).

I would use a loot table to make the monsters harder to kill and be more profitable in a more vanilla way, but I don't know whether it's possible, or how it would be done.

How can I link a mob's armour to a loot table's results?

Comment: It does. Thanks much @ExpertCoder14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `/loot` to replace the mob's armour:

```
execute as @e[tag=mob] run loot replace entity @s armor.feet 1 loot datapack:feet_loot
execute as @e[tag=mob] run loot replace entity @s armor.legs 1 loot datapack:legs_loot
...
```

and so on.